# Why does my =MATCH formula give #N/A or the correct answer in the exact same circumstance?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I'm trying to find the column number using a =match formula. In particular I am looking for a result of 42. As you can see, the formula looking in row 16 finds the number 24 in the 42nd row, and gives this result. However, the formula looking in row 17 does not.

The data is all in number format, and I have done equal checks to ensure 24 does indeed equal the value in both AQ16 and AQ17. Finally, AQ16 and AQ17 are also equal.

Both arrays are also able to find all the data correct (i.e. produce an array which includes the number 24 in the 42nd entry). Despite this, the formula in row 17 does not find 24 in the array, even though it is present.

[image: Data, formulas and checks]

Comment: That is really strange.  As a brain-storming, a few comment to check: 1) I assume you use `formulatext()` to show the formula, if not, please check the formula are really pointing to the correct ranges, 2) Is your "Workbook Calculation" option set to "Manual"?, 3) Are the numbers on row 16 & 17 static values or calculated by formula?

Comment: Hey Oliver,

I wasn't before but am now, I was just putting ' in front of the formula. No change after using 'formulatext()'. Workbook is set to manual as there is a large amount of calculation each time, but I have calculated the cell/sheet/workbook many times to no avail. The numbers on row 16 & 17 are static, however they have been copy pasted (values only) from a pivot table. This is because my formulas were behaving the same way when point at the pivot table, so I pulled out the two lines and formulas into one sheet as values only to see if the problem would still occur, and it does.